# Why does my function don't add proper data

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create an array of data which will be grouped by time (field_time_value).

This is the raw result of SQL query and I operate on this data ($query):

[image]

This is the result **I'd like to have** (desired) - all the closed keys has an empty value:

[image]

This is what I have right now (look at the value on [15.15][data][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFDLP.jpg)][data] - it's empty and according to data in $query it should be filled in, as above), all the closed keys has an empty value:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
  $days = array(
     1 => t('Monday'),
     2 => t('Tuesday'),
     3 => t('Wednesday'),
     4 => t('Thursday'),
     5 => t('Friday'),
     6 => t('Saturday'),
     7 => t('Sunday'),
  );

  foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    foreach($days as $day_key => $day_name) {
      if ($value->field_day_value == $day_key) {
        $rows[$value->field_time_value]['data'][$day_key] = array('data' => 'Day: '.$value->field_day_value.' Hour: '.$value->field_time_value);
      } else {
        $rows[$value->field_time_value]['data'][$day_key] = array('data' => 'empty');
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother anymore, I get the problem. There should be one more condition which will prevent from overriding data in my array:

```
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    foreach($days as $day_key => $day_name) {
      if ($value->field_day_value == $day_key) {
        $rows[$value->field_time_value]['data'][$day_key] = array('data' => 'Day: '.$value->field_day_value.' Hour: '.$value->field_time_value);
      } else {
        if (!isset($rows[$value->field_time_value]['data'][$day_key])) {
          $rows[$value->field_time_value]['data'][$day_key] = array('data' => 'empty');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```